# Rails Brakeman SQL injection warning while accessing an oracle view/function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, owasp, brakeman

I have rails code that is consuming an oracle view/function.
This is my code:

```
 def run_query
    connection.exec_query(
      "SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_REQ(#{demo_type_param},#{demo_tid_param}}))")
  end
```

When run Brakeman analyzer it warns of possible "sql injection attack"

I need to understand if this is a valid warning, if so, how do I remediate it?

Since this is a function & not an actual table, I am not sure what's the right way.
If it was a normal model, i would have just followed this pattern:

`Model.where("mycolumn1= ? AND mycolumn2= ?", demo_type_param, demo_tid_param).firs`t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is real. Almost every time, you build *any* SQL query from simply concatenating variables, you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Generally, an SQL injection happens each time when data inserted into the query can look like valid SQL and can result in additional queries executed.

The only solution is to manually enforce appropriate escaping or to use prepared statements, with the latter being the preferred solution.

With ActiveRecord / Rails, you can use [`exec_query`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements#exec_query-instance_method) with binds directly

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_REQ(?,?))'
connection.exec_query(sql, 'my query', [demo_type_param, demo_tid_param])
```

Here, Rails will prepare the statement on the database and add the parameters to it on execution, ensuring that everything is correctly escaped and save from SQL injection.

Comment: what does 'my query' represent above. Do we need it, since sql variable already has the query?

Comment: It is the name of the prepared statement which is added to the logs. It has no technical meaning for the query.

Comment: I get the error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for "'ALL'":String: SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_REQ(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))):

Comment: @Micheal This probably rewards a new question with the necessary details.

Comment: thanks i will dig more into it. it looks like its not selecting the params at all